# jQuery convert element ids into comma seperated string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple html and jquery script like below, I am trying to get a comma seperated list of data-item-id so would look like...

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

```js
var items = $('.container').children();
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-item-id="1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="5">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

I have grabbed the items but how can I convert this into the comma seperated string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map each item to its `item-id`, then join by commas:

```js
var items = $('.container')
  .children()
  .map(function() { return $(this).data('item-id') })
  .get()
  .join(',');
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-item-id="1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="5">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

But there's no need for a big library like jQuery to accomplish something this trivial, if you want:

```js
const items = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.container > .item'),
  div => div.dataset.itemId
)
  .join(',');
console.log(items);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-item-id="1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="5">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative with `JQuery` could be using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to traverse the `items` while grabbing the `data-item-id` with [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and adding it to a string.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var itemList = "";

    $('.container .item').each(function()
    {
        itemList += $(this).data('item-id') + ",";
    });

    console.log("Ids:", itemList.slice(0,-1));
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-item-id="1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="5">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because who wouldn't want to add destructuring as well ..... (Kudos to CertainPerformance)

```js
const items = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.container > .item'),
  ({ dataset: { itemId: i } }) => i
)
  .join(',');
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-item-id="1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="5">Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can also apply some features of ES5 and ES6 for a shorter solution. And without *jQuery*.

```js
let itemsIds = [...document.getElementsByClassName("item")]
    .map(elem => elem.getAttribute("data-item-id"))
    .join(',');
console.log(itemsIds);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-item-id="1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-item-id="5">Item 5</div>
</div>
```